# What is the meaning of 第ー部

Tags: translation

In attempting to translate an advertising poster, I ran into some difficulties. The poster reads:

第一部　ガールズバンドライブ

第二部　カウントダウンライブ

The katakana is easy enough: 'Girl Band Live / Countdown Live', but in checking the kanji on jisho, I'm finding the meanings of 'ordinal' and 'club, category, or magazine counter', none of which seems to mesh together. 'First Club / Second Club' are my best guesses, but it doesn't quite seem to fit. Does anyone have an accurate translation?

Comment: Wouldn't this be "first act" and "second act"?  Meaning that Girl Band opens then Countdown follows.  I speak zero Japanese but if I saw a club poster that said (as this does) "1. blah-blah-blah / 2. blah-blah-blah", that is what I would assume it meant.

Comment: If it's chapter/episode titles of manga/anime, then translate it with the context of that manga/anime. Some manga/anime will use different words in place of the usual character for "chapter".

Answer (score 2):

My best guess with the 部 counter for this would be part one, part two, etc. According to jisho.org, 部 can also mean a "part; component; element" so in this context it would make sense to be Part one: girl band live, Part two: countdown live.

Answer (score 2):

It is used this way to mean like "session", "period", or (more limited) "service".  My church (and others) in Japan counted their Sunday worship services this way:  `一部礼拝 (1st Service)、二部礼拝 (2nd Service)、三部礼拝 (3rd Service)、 etc.`

BTW, did it really have ガーラズ for "garage"?  It's usually written ガレージ.

Comment: Maybe it was actually [ガールズバンド](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BA%E3%83%90%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89)?

Comment: It was. I fixed it in the original post. My apologies for the typo. So it looks like the katakana was 'girl band', not 'garage band'. Whoops.